# Trying to write a file to an Array - getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, arrays, nosuchelementexception

(For this I need to use Arrays - not Array lists. Snipping code to make it easier to follow. Renaming variables and constants to label so others who read this later understand what I am doing better.)

At the class level I have my arrays defined like so:

```
private static final int CONSTANT = 20;
public static String[] arrayName = new String[CONSTANT - 1];
```

and in the main method I am pointing to the method like so:

```
readArrays("filenName.txt", arrayName);
```

and a line like that points to the following complete method which is where the error occurs:

```
    public static void readArrays(String codeFile, 
                                 String[] Arrays)
 {        

   try ( Scanner fin = new Scanner ( new File(codeFile) ); ) 
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < CONSTANT - 1; i++) 
          {
          Arrays[i] = fin.next();
          }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.err.println( "Read Error: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
```

It shows no errors in NetBeans, but in the console window the exact error message is:

```
 run:
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at mp06.Main.readArrays(Main.java:47)
    at mp06.Main.main(Main.java:33)
 Java Result: 1
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What is causing this error? Ultimately, my goal is to write the entire contents of multiple text files to multiple arrays using the same method and without using any other approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    try ( Scanner fin = new Scanner ( new File(codeFile) ); ) 
    {
     for (int i = 0; i < CONSTANT - 1 && fin.hasNext(); i++) 
          {
          Arrays[i] = fin.next();
          }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.err.println( "Read Error: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
```

You also need to check ***Scanner*** has next.

In ***Java8***, you can use ***stream*** to read file:

```
List<String> contents = Files.lines(Paths.get("filenName.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the error, but now I have a new problem: testing it with: System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(Arrays)); results in 20 nulls.

Comment: Did you check if the path to your file is correct? Maybe the file can't be found. Did you use relative or absolute paths?

Comment: I copied the text files into the project directory (which I created in a separate project entirely). I'm sure the names are spelled correctly. Do they need to be visible in the project list within Netbeans?

EDIT: Scratch that, turns out something I did previously with this new program overwrote the files with blank space. After copying them back over fresh everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

The below code might help you.
There are couple of things, you have to check whether next element is exists in scanner before you call next() and the other one is the constant "20", it will end up with Array Index Bounds exception if the size exceeds 20.

Adding them in the list and converting them to an array will resolve this. Try the below code.

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    while (fin.hasNext()) {
        list.add(fin.next());
    }

    String[] array = new String[list.size()];
    list.toArray(array);

    for (String str: array) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```